# How to detect OS Version in Firefox Extension which is made with Addon SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to know how to detect OS Version in Firefox Extension which is made with Addon SDK.
Can I detect it in my main.js?

Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, the closest you can get is the OS type. See the SDK's `system` module:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/system#platform

var system = require("sdk/system");
console.log("platform = " + system.platform);
// returns things like 'winnt', 'linux' and 'darwin'

You could use the [child_process](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/system_child_process) module to run `uname` on UNIX systems or `ver` on Windows to get additional info.